# KeyError en key value pairs

Tags: python

Me está saltando un error que no consigo encontrar el motivo.

Pego el código y el error a ver si alguien puede echarme una mano.

```
def prepareForInference(bucket,kvs):
    df = pd.DataFrame(kvs.items())
    print('got the dataframe')
    df.columns = ['key','value']
    df1 = df[df.value != '']
    df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
    df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[1:7])
    df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
    df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[4])
    df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
    df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[9:12])
    df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
    df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[5:7])
    df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
    df_T = df1.T
    print("in the middle of all the dataframe operations")
    df_T.columns = df_T.iloc[0]
    df_T = df_T.reset_index(drop=True)
    df_T = df_T.drop([0])
    df_T = df_T.reset_index(drop=True)
    df_T = df_T.rename(columns={"Name (First, Middle, Last, Suffix) ": "Name", "Date of Birth (mm/dd/yyyy) ": "Date of Birth"})
    df_T.columns = df_T.columns.str.rstrip()
    data_key = prefix+"/cer-input/"+str(uuid.uuid4())+'laminference.csv'
    entry = ''
    for idx, row in df_T.iterrows():
            entry += 'Country'+':'+str(row['Country']).strip()+" "+'Years'+':'+str(row['Years']).strip()+" "+'Cell Phone'+':'+str(row['Cell Phone']).strip()+" "+'Name'+':'+str(row['Name']).strip()+" "+'Social Security Number'+':'+str(row['Social Security Number']).strip()+" "+'TOTAL $'+':'+str(row['TOTAL $']).strip()+" "+'Date of Birth'+':'+str(row['Date of Birth']).strip()+'\n'
```

Y aquí el error: (edito para mayor comprehensión)

```
got the key value pairs: {'Own ': 'X ', 'Country ': 'US ', 'Unit # ': '', 'Home Phone ': '( ) - ', 'Married ': 'X ', 'Commission ': '$ /month ', 'State ': '', 'Permanent Resident Alien ': '', 'Phone ': '( ) - ', 'Cell Phone ': '(555 ) 0200 1234 ', 'I am applying for individual credit. ': 'X ', 'Separated ': '', 'U.S. Citizen ': 'X ', 'Ext. ': '', 'Work Phone ': '( ) - ', 'Non-Permanent Resident Alien ': '', 'Employer or Business Name ': '', 'Months ': '', 'Years ': '', 'ZIP ': '', 'Street ': '', 'Ages ': '', 'Email ': '', 'Overtime ': '$ /month ', 'Name (First, Middle, Last, Suffix) ': 'Kwaku Mensah ', 'Does not apply ': 'X ', 'Number ': '', 'Agency Case No. ': '', 'City ': 'Any City ', 'Rent ($ /month) ': '', 'Bonus ': '$ /month ', 'Check if you are the Business Owner or Self-Employed ': '', 'Social Security Number ': '123 - 45 - 6789 ', 'No primary housing expense ': '', 'Position or Title ': '', 'Military Entitlements ': '$ /month ', 'Start Date ': '/ / ', 'Date of Birth (mm/dd/yyyy) ': '01 / 01 / 1953 ', 'Base ': '$ 8,000.00 /month ', 'TOTAL $ ': '8000.00/month ', 'List Name(s) of Other Borrower(s) Applying for this Loan (First, Middle, Last, Suffix) - Use a separator between names ': '', 'have an ownership share of less than 25%. Monthly Income (or ': '', 'Other ': '$ /month ', 'have an ownership share of 25% or more. $ ': '', 'Lender Loan No./Universal Loan Identifier ': '', 'Alternate Names - List any names by which you are known or any names under which credit was previously received (First, Middle, Last, Suffix) ': '', 'Unmarried ': '', 'Borrower intends to apply for joint credit. Your initials: ': '', 'am applying for joint credit. Total Number of Borrowers: ': ''}

2021-07-02T12:17:37.431+02:00


got the dataframe

2021-07-02T12:17:37.474+02:00

in the middle of all the dataframe operations

2021-07-02T12:17:37.511+02:00

[ERROR] KeyError: 'Country'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/TextractComprehend.py", line 173, in lambda_handler
    inkey = prepareForInference(bucket,kvs)
  File "/var/task/TextractComprehend.py", line 135, in prepareForInference
    entry += 'Country'+':'+str(row['Country']).strip()+" "+'Years'+':'+str(row['Years']).strip()+" "+'Cell Phone'+':'+str(row['Cell Phone']).strip()+" "+'Name'+':'+str(row['Name']).strip()+" "+'Social Security Number'+':'+str(row['Social Security Number']).strip()+" "+'TOTAL $'+':'+str(row['TOTAL $']).strip()+" "+'Date of Birth'+':'+str(row['Date of Birth']).strip()+'\n'
  File "/opt/python/pandas/core/series.py", line 853, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "/opt/python/pandas/core/series.py", line 961, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "/opt/python/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

[ERROR] KeyError: 'Country' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/TextractComprehend.py", line 173, in lambda_handler     inkey = prepareForInference(bucket,kvs)   File "/var/task/TextractComprehend.py", line 135, in prepareForInference     entry += 'Country'+':'+str(row['Country']).strip()+" "+'Years'+':'+str(row['Years']).strip()+" "+'Cell Phone'+':'+str(row['Cell Phone']).strip()+" "+'Name'+':'+str(row['Name']).strip()+" "+'Social Security Number'+':'+str(row['Social Security Number']).strip()+" "+'TOTAL $'+':'+str(row['TOTAL $']).strip()+" "+'Date of Birth'+':'+str(row['Date of Birth']).strip()+'\n'   File "/opt/python/pandas/core/series.py", line 853, in __getitem__     return self._get_value(key)   File "/opt/python/pandas/core/series.py", line 961, in _get_value     loc = self.index.get_loc(label)   File "/opt/python/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc     raise KeyError(key) from err
```

Parece que lo que no encuentra es str(row['Country']).strip() pero Country sí aparece en la cadena de arriba. Pasa con cualquier bloque, salta en Country porque es el primero.

Gracias de antemano!!!

Edito para añadir todo el código porque sigo sin encontrar el error.

He probado añadiendo un espacio en str(row['Country']).strip() y sustituyendolo por row.loc['Country'] y nada.

```
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus
import pandas as pd
import json
import boto3
import re
import sys
import uuid

prefix = 'intelligent-doc-demo'
# Create an SSM Client
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')

    # Create an S3 Client
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    # Create a Textract Client
textract_client = boto3.client('textract')

    # Create a Comprehend Client
comprehend_client = boto3.client('comprehend')


def get_kv_map(bucket,key):

    # process using image bytes

    response = textract_client.analyze_document(Document={'S3Object': {
            'Bucket': bucket,
            'Name': key
        }}, FeatureTypes=['FORMS'])
    print('got the image')
    # Get the text blocks
    blocks=response['Blocks']


    # get key and value maps
    key_map = {}
    value_map = {}
    block_map = {}
    for block in blocks:
        block_id = block['Id']
        block_map[block_id] = block
        if block['BlockType'] == "KEY_VALUE_SET":
            if 'KEY' in block['EntityTypes']:
                key_map[block_id] = block
            else:
                value_map[block_id] = block

    return key_map, value_map, block_map


def get_kv_relationship(key_map, value_map, block_map):
    kvs = {}
    for block_id, key_block in key_map.items():
        value_block = find_value_block(key_block, value_map)
        key = get_text(key_block, block_map)
        val = get_text(value_block, block_map)
        kvs[key] = val
    return kvs


def find_value_block(key_block, value_map):
    for relationship in key_block['Relationships']:
        if relationship['Type'] == 'VALUE':
            for value_id in relationship['Ids']:
                value_block = value_map[value_id]
    return value_block


def get_text(result, blocks_map):
    text = ''
    if 'Relationships' in result:
        for relationship in result['Relationships']:
            if relationship['Type'] == 'CHILD':
                for child_id in relationship['Ids']:
                    word = blocks_map[child_id]
                    if word['BlockType'] == 'WORD':
                        text += word['Text'] + ' '
                    if word['BlockType'] == 'SELECTION_ELEMENT':
                        if word['SelectionStatus'] == 'SELECTED':
                            text += 'X '


    return text

def prepareForInference(bucket,kvs):
    df = pd.DataFrame(kvs.items())
    print('got the dataframe')
    df.columns = ['key','value']
    df1 = df[df.value != '']
    df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
    df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[1:7])
    df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
    df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[4])
    df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
    df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[9:12])
    df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
    df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[5:7])
    df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
    df_T = df1.T
    print("in the middle of all the dataframe operations")
    df_T.columns = df_T.iloc[0]
    df_T = df_T.reset_index(drop=True)
    df_T = df_T.drop([0])
    df_T = df_T.reset_index(drop=True)
    df_T = df_T.rename(columns={"Name (First, Middle, Last, Suffix) ": "Name", "Date of Birth (mm/dd/yyyy) ": "Date of Birth"})
    df_T.columns = df_T.columns.str.rstrip()
    data_key = prefix+"/cer-input/"+str(uuid.uuid4())+'laminference.csv'
    entry = ''
    for idx, row in df_T.iterrows():
        entry += 'Country'+':'+str(row['Country ']).strip()+" "+'Years'+':'+str(row['Years']).strip()+" "+'Cell Phone'+':'+str(row['Cell Phone']).strip()+" "+'Name'+':'+str(row['Name']).strip()+" "+'Social Security Number'+':'+str(row['Social Security Number']).strip()+" "+'TOTAL $'+':'+str(row['TOTAL $']).strip()+" "+'Date of Birth'+':'+str(row['Date of Birth']).strip()+'\n'
    print('done done and done')
    # Store Processed Data in S3 Bucket
    processed_textract_data_response = s3_client.put_object(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key=data_key,
        Body=json.dumps(entry)
    )
    return data_key

def lambda_handler(event, context):


    # Get the Custom Entity Recognizer's ARN from SSM Parameter Store
    comprehend_parameters = ssm_client.get_parameters(Names=['CustomEntityRecognizerARN-TCA2I',
                                                             'ComprehendExecutionRole-TCA2I', 'S3OutBucketName-TCA2I'],
                                                      WithDecryption=True)

    for parameter in comprehend_parameters['Parameters']:
        if parameter['Name'] == 'CustomEntityRecognizerARN-TCA2I':
            custom_recognizer_arn = parameter['Value']
        elif parameter['Name'] == 'ComprehendExecutionRole-TCA2I':
            comprehend_execution_role_arn = parameter['Value']
        elif parameter['Name'] == 'S3OutBucketName-TCA2I':
            out_bucket = parameter['Value']

    # Iterate over all S3 Put records that have been passed to this lambda function.
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'])

        # get key value pairs from the uploaded input document
        key_map, value_map, block_map = get_kv_map(bucket,key)
        # Get Key Value relationship
        kvs = get_kv_relationship(key_map, value_map, block_map)
        print('got the key value pairs: ' + str(kvs))
        # Transform using a dataframe, create CSV file and load to S3 for Comprehend Inference as a next step
        inkey = prepareForInference(bucket,kvs)
        print('uploaded the inference file')

    # Start the Custom Entity Recognition Job
    response = comprehend_client.start_entities_detection_job(
        InputDataConfig={
            'S3Uri': 's3://' + bucket + '/' + inkey,
            'InputFormat': 'ONE_DOC_PER_LINE'
        },
        OutputDataConfig={
            'S3Uri': 's3://' + out_bucket + '/'+ prefix+'/cer-output/'
        },
        DataAccessRoleArn=comprehend_execution_role_arn,
        JobName=  str(uuid.uuid4()) + '-TextractComprehendA2I',
        EntityRecognizerArn=custom_recognizer_arn,
        LanguageCode='en'
    )
    print("Custom Entity Detection Job Started")

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('I did what I was asked to do!')
    }
```

Comment: Buenas, Toni, bienvenido al sitio. Por favor, copia tu error como texto en lugar de como imagen para mejorar la legibilidad y facilitar búsquedas relacionadas. Aparte de eso, no tengo mucha idea de python, pero la mayoría de nombres de tus claves tienen un espacio al final. Veo un rename de algunas de ellas pero no de la que te da error, "Country", que aparece como "Country ". ¿Puede ser ese espacio el que te cause el error?

Comment: Hola! Ya lo he editado. Sobre el espacio que hay, con el .strip de la cadena, debe saltarse cualquier espacio que haya delante o detrás por lo que entiendo que ahí no está el problema.

Comment: La notacion `df[`country`]` es para escoger una columna si vas a escoger slgun dato de una fila, es mejor utilizar loc o iloc

Comment: @Toni Sí, si el strip lo conozco, pero ten en cuenta que lo haces DESPUES de intentar recuperar el valor asociado a "Country".

Comment: Prueba a cambiar 'Country' por 'Country ' en str(row['Country']).strip() a ver si así recupera el valor asociado correctamente.

Comment: Lo mejor para estos casos es poner los datos ya que sino estaremos adivinando

Comment: @RubioRic he añadido el espacio y nada, sigue dando error.

Comment: @Christian sustituirlo por loc sería row.loc['Country'] por ejemplo? Voy a probar a ver que me devuelve

Comment: Buenas, Toni, como te decía no soy experto en python, me temo. Lo que no veo en tu código es donde escribes esto "got the key value pairs:". Entre sea donde sea y el punto donde quieres acceder al valor de Country, algo está pasando.

Comment: Voy a colgar todo el codigo a ver si encontramos el error. Gracias!!!